# Resource placement (optimal strategy)

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics, game-theory

I know that this is not exactly the right place to ask this question, but maybe a wise guy comes across and has the solution.

I'm trying to write a computer game and I need an algorithm to solve this question:

The game is played between 2 players. Each side has 1.000 dollars. There are three "boxes" and each player writes down the amount of money he is going to place into those boxes. Then these amounts are compared. Whoever placed more money in a box scores 1 point (if draw half point each). Whoever scores more points wins his opponents 1.000 dollars. Example game:

Player A: [500, 500, 0]
Player B: [333, 333, 334]

Player A wins because he won Box A and Box B (but lost Box C).

Question: What is the optimal strategy to place the money?

I have more questions to ask (algorithm related, not math related) but I need to know the answer to this one first.

**Update (1):** After some more research I've learned that these type of problems/games are called [Colonel Blotto Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blotto_games). I did my best and found few (highly technical) documents on the subject. Cutting it short, the problem I have (as described above) is called simple Blotto Game (only three battlefields with symmetric resources). The difficult ones are the ones with, say, 10+ battle fields with non-symmetric resources. All the documents I've read say that the simple Blotto game is easy to solve. The thing is, none of them actually say what that "easy" solution is.

**Update (2):** I wrote a small actionscript file to demonstrate the strategy in the paper mentioned by Tom Sirgedas. You can test it at [megaswf](http://megaswf.com/serve/1038463). Instructions: Click a point inside the triangle. Red region represent winning cases. Blue region represents losing cases, tiny whitish lines represents draw.

Comment: Is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_attrition_(game)?

Comment: The link is broken (I can't fix it). Copy & paste it if you want to visit the site, as that last parentheses isn't part of the URL when you posted it.

Comment: We can eliminate the 'put all eggs in one basket' solution

Comment: Just checked this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_attrition_%28game%29. Don't see how that related to my question.

Comment: Orbit: Yes, sure. Moreover there is no single best strategy. These type of games are called non-transitive---whatever your strategy is, there is always a better one. So, the player(s) should adopt what is called "mixed strategy".

Comment: I've poked around with an LP solver and the Nash equilibrium seems not to have an obvious, nice description. Where are you going with this?

Comment: This is a fun question. My impulse would be to try to find two strategies where any solution that beats one 2/3 of the time would lose to the other equally often. Then choose between them randomly...

Comment: A link is worth adding: - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium - and before anyone asks, yes, a *very* distant relation. Since this is for a game, I'd suggest you experiment with, say $10 first, and find what the decent strategies look like against a player that distributes the 10 items 'randomly' (i.e. equally likely to choose any of the, I think, 66 possible distributions). That might be good enough.

Comment: I think there's little point to this game (it is too random) if it's played on a single round. A winning strategy could be devised for a several rounds game, but it would likely be one as those for Poker: it depends on what the opponent is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an optimal strategy in this paper: http://www.rand.org/pubs/research_memoranda/2006/RM408.pdf

Let's call this Blotto's strategy.

### [image]

Look at the diagram above.  Any move you make can be represented by a point on the triangle.  The strategy in the paper says to pick a point at random in the hexagon.  Choose points closer to the edge of the hexagon with higher probability (0 probability for the center of the hexagon, and linearly scale up to the maximum probability at the hexagon outline.  Every point on the hexagon outline has equal probability.)

This solution is for "continuous" Blotto, but I assume you are interested in the discrete case (dividing N troops into 3 groups).  Applying Blotto's strategy to the discrete case works perfectly well, when N is a multiple of 3.  For other values of N, I was able to make a small adjustment on the hexagon border that works very well, but not perfectly.

If there is a strategy that can defeat this one, there must be some static move which wins  against Blotto's strategy.  There is none, except for when N is not a multiple of 3, then it seems that a move on the line where the big triangle and hexagon meet (e.g. the move <0,.5,.5>) will win against Blotto's strategy *slightly* more than lose.  For N=100, the difference seems to be less than 1%, and continues to shrink for larger N.

Code to implement Blotto's strategy:

```
// generate a random number in the range [0,x) -- compensate for rand()%x being slightly un-uniform
int rnd( int x ) { int r; while ( 1 ) { r = rand(); if ( r < RAND_MAX/x*x ) return r % x; } }

// distance from center of triangle/hexagon to (x,y,z), multiplied by 3 (trilinear coordinates)
int hexagonalDist3( int x, int y, int z, int N ) { return max(max(abs(N-x*3),abs(N-y*3)),abs(N-z*3)); }

void generateRandomSimpleBlottoMove( int& x, int& y, int& z, int totalTroops )
{
   int N = totalTroops;
   while ( true )
   {
      x = rnd(N+1);
      y = rnd(N+1);
      z = N-x-y;

      // keep only moves in hexagon, with moves closer to the border having higher probability
      double relativeProbabilityOfKeepingThisMove = hexagonalDist3(x,y,z,N) > N ? 0 : hexagonalDist3(x,y,z,N);

      // minor adjustment for hexagon border when N is not a multiple of 3 -- not perfect, but "very close"
      if ( N % 3 != 0 && hexagonalDist3(x,y,z,N) == N ) 
         relativeProbabilityOfKeepingThisMove = N*(N%3)/3; 

      // possibly keep our move 
      if ( rnd(N) < relativeProbabilityOfKeepingThisMove )
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, any move within the hexagon is equally likely to win as it is to lose against Blotto's strategy.  Moves outside the hexagon are more likely to lose than to win against Blotto's strategy.

Comment: Thank you for sparing your time, Tom. I still don't understand why this strategy is optimal, but I'll do my best to absorb it.

Comment: No problem, this one was very interesting.  Try this: pick a point on the triangle.  Now find all points on the triangle which your chosen point defeats, and color them red.  You should see that you drew the "Mitsubishi" logo, centered on your chosen point.  Note that you lose to all un-colored points.

Comment: Now, instead make your strategy to choose among 2 points, with equal prob.  You should be able to identify which opponent moves you will win against 100%, 50%, and 0%.  An optimal strategy will win at least 50% of the time against any move/point.  Instead of choosing among a few discrete points, we might choose a point on the border of the hexagon at random.  This seems to win 50% of the time against any move within the hex, but only wins ~33% of the time against any move barely outside the hexagon (found by computer program).  I hope that provides some insight!

Comment: Tom: Am I missing something here? As I understand, choosing points on the outline of the hexagon is a superior strategy. Just to make a "very" simple test class, I defined this array [(200, 100, 0), (200, 0, 100), (100, 200, 0), (100, 0, 200), (0, 100, 200), (0, 200, 100)] and the computer make random troops (adding up to 300). I run the game for, say, 1000 times and the score is usually 450 for superior strategy and 550 for random pick. As I said, I must be missing something.

Comment: Picking randomly among those 6 points is NOT a good strategy.  It loses to a random point, or to (120,120,60) 2 out of 3 times, for example.  If you just want to defeat the "random point" strategy, pick (100,100,100) each time (you'll win 2 out of 3 times).  If you want to implement Blotto's strategy, you need to pick a point in the hexagon, but prefer points closer to the edge of the hexagon (in a specific way).  I included code to implement Blotto's strategy in my post.

Answer (score 0):

So this actually is a game theory question (economics) not a discrete math problem, re-tagging your question might attract the kind of attention you want. In game theory, the idea of a "solution" is usually [Nash equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium). for zero sum games, it turns out the algorithm you want to solve this is a linear programming problem. See this wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum) for an example of how to set it up.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that it would be fairly easy to prove that this game has no pure Nash equilibrium. A pure strategy is a fixed one, like [333,333,334]. My sketch of a proof is as follows:

> For any pure strategy played by player
>   A, player B can find another pure
>   strategy that gets B 2 points. For
>   example, if A plays [500,500,0] then B
>   plays [501,0,499], or if A plays
>   [333,333,334] then B plays
>   [500,500,0], and so on. There is
>   always a way to get 2 points. Of
>   course, this means that player A would
>   get 1 point.
>
> Similarly, for any strategy played by
>   player B, player A can find another
>   pure strategy that gets him 2. Thus,
>   no pure Nash exists.

Also, I think that it can be proven that the strategy (for both) of

1/3 [500,500,0],
1/3 [500,0,500],
1/3 [0,500,500]

(play [500,500,0] with 1/3 probability and [500,0,500] with 1/3 probability and [0,500,500] with 1/3 probability) is a mixed Nash equilibrium for this game. Under this strategy their expected gain (#points) is 3/2. The proof seems laborious to me. Maybe someone else will have a simple proof.

A mixed Nash is as closed to "optimal" as we can get. There are probably other mixed Nash equilibria for this game.

Comment: A random permutation of [500,500,0] has negative expected value against a random permutation of [998,1,1].

Comment: Agree with userOver9000. The mixed strategy solution you propose isn't a Nash equilibrium.